# VBScript to enable / disable proxy

Tags: windows, vbscript, proxy

I'm trying to create a script to go into startup applications which will automatically set the proxy in my workplace. The idea is this however I'm new to VBScript and I keep getting an error.

```
Option Explicit 
Dim WSHShell, strSetting
ans = msgbox("Are you working in the office?" , vbyesno) 
If ans = vbyes then 
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer", "10.2.2.88:8090", "REG_SZ"
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride", "*.dev;*.test;*.local;<local>", "REG_SZ"
else
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"
End If
```

Can somebody show me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your error is something as follows:

```
==>cscript //nologo D:\VB_scripts\SO\28832310.vbs
28832310.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'ans'
```

Self-explanatory message, *IMHO*. As you have used `Option Explicit`  statement correctly  (forces explicit declaration of all variables in a script), simply add `ans` variable declaration, i.e.  use

```
 Dim WSHShell, strSetting, ans
```